# Metadata explorer to view workflows

Tags: workflow, metadata

There are quite a few good tools on AppExchange to view metadata components, such as objects and code, but none of them seem to be able to display workflows.

Using Eclipse IDE is a bit of a pain, as XML is not highly readable and exporting them to Excel regularly is a pain.

Does anyone know of a viewer that can outline workflows in an easy to read format?

Comment: Do you mean the original workflow feature, or *visual* workflow, in other words, "Flows"?

Comment: Original workflow feature.

Comment: Why do you need AppExchange tool to view workflows ? You can view them via setup menu. The UI is also very user friendly.

Comment: The UI is user friendly, however it's not very friendly once you have 100s of workflows and field updates. Why do you think there are bunch of tools to explore metadata?

Answer (score 1):

You may have to wait a bit yet, but according to a recent [review](https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000009wgF7EAI) response,  from Chirag Mehta, on "Metadata Search" they are working on adding workflow rules and validation rules.

> Chirag Mehta Hi Alex,
>
> Thank you once again for your interest in "Metadata Search".
>
> To make things easier for you, we have added the ability to search
>   inside code!
>
> Metadata Search App now supports searching inside Apex Triggers, Apex
>   Classes, Visualforce Pages or Visualforce Components. For e.g.,
>   Searching for "BillingCity__c" will find all metadata components along
>   with all Apex Triggers, Apex Classes, Visualforce Pages or Visualforce
>   Components containing "BillingCity__c”.
>
> Do try out and Let us know your valuable feedback. We are now working
>   on adding support for workflows and validation rules, will keep you
>   posted once we are able to support same.
>
> Need help? No Problem! Contact Us at support@satrangtech.com
>
> Chirag

Comment: The response is half year old.

Comment: Unfortunately, they don't have an eta either, I reached out to them this morning and they are having problems working with Salesforce on this one. Their support was great though, they called me within 5 minutes of sending the email to explain why they don't have an eta yet.

Comment: @JennyB, my apologies for long delay here in publishing these changes. But Salesforce limitations (wrt Apex etc) is not allowing me to do search of these items (workflows and validation rules) directly. Hence its taking time to come out with robust and comprehensive solution to be able to search workflows and validation rules along with other metadata components.